# Design: Is it correct to push records to database first and then pick from database and push to rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

We are e-commerce website with several listings. The listings can be created/updated/deleted from various apps:- i.e. desktop, mobile, apps.

We need to push all this updated information to some third party APIs i.e. any new listing created/deleted or if the existing listing updates, we need to push complete listing information through some third party API. We are using Rabbitmq for this since we expect a high volume of record update.

We have two choices:

- Push from all endpoints (desk/msite/app) info like (listingId, Action on listing i.e. CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE) to rabbitmq. Rabbitmq further dequeue these messages and hit appropriate API.
- Implement trigger on listings table i.e. on create, insert entry into some table with column (listingId, database action to be executed i.e. CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE). Now, create a job toread from this table after every 10 sec. and push these to rabbitmq.

Which is better appraoch?

Answer (score 2):

I think an HTTP based API might be the best solution. You can implement a gateway which includes security (OAuth2/SAML), rate limiting etc. Internally you can use RabbitMQ. The gateway can publish the updates to RabbitMQ and have subscribers which write the data to your master database and other subscribers that publish the data to your third party APIs.

The added benefit of an HTTP gateway, beyond the extra security controls available, is that you could change your mind about RabbitMQ in the future without impacting your desktop and mobile apps which would be difficult to update in their entirety.

Having worked with databases for most of my career, I tend to avoid triggers. Especially if you expect large volumes of updates. I have experienced performance problems and reliability problems with triggers in the past.

It is worth noting that RabbitMQ does have message duplication problems - there is no exactly once delivery guarantee. So you will need to implement your own deduplication or preferably make all actions idempotent.

Comment: +1.  Another point against the trigger solution:  what if someone writes a procedure later on down the line that updates entries in your `listing` table multiple times in a transaction?  Your `listing_updates` table now contains updates that didn't really exist at any point in time... in other words, it's difficult to discern what constitutes a 'real' update vs. an 'intermediate' update within a trigger.  You don't have much context.

Comment: In addition...the database/trigger solution requires you to maintain yet another message queue (your hand-rolled database table!), and if you find yourself needing the 'exactly once delivery' guarantee, you'll find yourself in a tricky spot.  What if your polling service crashes?  If the polling service can't reach the rabbitMQ?  If the polling service can reach rabbitMQ but can't clear out the table afterwards?  More difficult than it seems.